# Python Panda : Count number of occurence of a number

Tags: python, pandas, data-science

I've searched for long time and I need your help, I'm newbie on python and panda lib. I've a dataframe like that charged from a csv file :

```
ball_1,ball_2,ball_3,ball_4,ball_5,ball_6,ball_7,extraball_1,extraball_2
10,32,25,5,8,19,21,3,4
43,12,8,19,4,37,12,1,5
12,16,43,19,4,28,40,2,4
```

ball_X is an int in between 1-50 and extraball_X is an int between 1-9. I want count how many times appear each number in 2 other frames like that :
First DF ball :

```
Number,Score
1,128
2,34
3,12
4,200
....
50,145
```

Second DF extraball :

```
Number,Score
1,340
2,430
3,123
4,540
....
9,120
```

I've the algorythme in my head but i'm too noob in panda to translate into code.
I Hope it's clear enough and someone will be able to help me. Dont hesitate if you have questions.

Comment: Please post your expected output.

Answer (score 3):

#### `groupby` on `columns` with `value_counts`

```
def get_before_underscore(x):
    return x.split('_', 1)[0]

val_counts = {
    k: d.stack().value_counts()
    for k, d in df.groupby(get_before_underscore, axis=1)
}

print(val_counts['ball'])

12    3
19    3
4     2
8     2
43    2
32    1
5     1
10    1
37    1
40    1
16    1
21    1
25    1
28    1
dtype: int64

print(val_counts['extraball'])

4    2
1    1
2    1
3    1
5    1
dtype: int64
```

Comment: Hello
Thanks for your help, I had too adapt it a little but worked great. It permits me to learn how do it. Thanks a lot, have a nice weekend.